# Hyper-V Failover Cluster MAC Address Handeling

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

Can someone please explain how MAC address assignment works in a hyper-v cluster? I have a couple machines that need to have a static MAC address assigned and want to know how the cluster handles it when the VM is Live migrated to a new host. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. The MAC address moves. What is the question?

It is similar to pulling the plug and plugging it in on another port. Likely the Hyper-V host after the migration is sending some ARP packets so the switch knows the port has changed, but that is it. As the VM configuration does not change, neither does the MAC address.

Comment: Ok so when would someone use a dynamic vs static MAC address. In regards to hyper-v?

Comment: Please explain how you create something like a dynamic MAC address in HyperV.